# ICS Force stopped application saying Out of Bounds but sometimes runs just fine

Tags: android

I have some trouble in my app where sometimes it works and displays all the data I need but sometimes It just force closed my app saying an Out Of Bounds Exception on phone logs. By the way it works just fine in my emulator. Don't know what to do anymore so asking for help out there. Here's my phone log. To add it only happens in ICS but not on Gingerbread.

```
V/data content(11074): Data1
V/data id  (11074): 0
V/data name(11074): Data Name
V/data time(11074): Aug 25, 2012 10:00 PM
D/AndroidRuntime(11074): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(11074): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c531f8)
E/AndroidRuntime(11074): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(11074): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
E/AndroidRuntime(11074):        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
E/AndroidRuntime(11074):        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
E/AndroidRuntime(11074):        at com.android.guestlist.DataActivity.showMyRsvp(RsvpActivity.java:167)
E/AndroidRuntime(11074):        at com.android.guestlist.DataActivity$AsyncGetRsvp.onPostExecute(DataActivity.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(11074):        at com.android.guestlist.DataActivity$AsyncGetRsvp.onPostExecute(DataActivity.java:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(11074):        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
E/AndroidRuntime(11074):        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
E/AndroidRuntime(11074):        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
E/AndroidRuntime(11074):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(11074):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(11074):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
E/AndroidRuntime(11074):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(NativeMethod)
E/AndroidRuntime(11074):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(11074):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
E/AndroidRuntime(11074):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
E/AndroidRuntime(11074):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager( 2089):   Force finishing activity com.android.guestlist/.CustomTabActivity
E/android.os.Debug( 2089): !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -n -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

Here's my Activity code:

```
    public class RsvpActivity extends Activity {

    JSONArray jArray;
    String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb=null;

    String fb_id = "";
    String first_name = "";
    String last_name = "";
    String gender = "";

    public static List<String> eId3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static List<String> eBar3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static List<String> eName3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static List<String> eTime3 = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        fb_id =  getIntent().getStringExtra("fb_id");
        first_name =  getIntent().getStringExtra("first_name");
        last_name =  getIntent().getStringExtra("last_name");
        gender =  getIntent().getStringExtra("gender");

        setContentView(R.layout.rsvp);
    }

    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        new AsyncGetRsvp().execute(fb_id, "MY URL HERE");
    }

    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        new AsyncGetRsvp().execute(fb_id, "MY URL HERE");
    }

    public class AsyncGetRsvp extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<String>>{
        private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(RsvpActivity.this);

        @Override
        protected List<String> doInBackground(String... params) {
            getRsvp(params[0], params[1]);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
             this.dialog.setMessage("Getting RSVPs");
             this.dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {
            showMyRsvp();
            if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
                this.dialog.dismiss();
             }
        }

    }


    public void showMyRsvp(){
        // Get the TableLayout
        final TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.maintable2);
        tl.removeAllViewsInLayout();


        // Go through each item in the array
        for (int current = 0; current < eId3.size(); current++)
        {
            Log.v("bar content",eBar3.get(current));
            Log.v("bar id",eId3.get(current));
            Log.v("bar name",eName3.get(current));
            Log.v("bar time",eTime3.get(current));


            // Create a TableRow and give it an ID
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            tr.setId(100+current);
            tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));   

            // Create a TextView to house the name of the province
            final TextView clubName = new TextView(this);
            clubName.setId(200+current);
            clubName.setText(eBar3.get(current));
            clubName.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            clubName.setTextSize(12);
            clubName.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            clubName.setTag(eId3.get(current));
            clubName.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            clubName.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 65, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()),
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tr.addView(clubName);

            //CREATE TEXT VIEW FOR EVENT NAME
            TextView eventName = new TextView(this);
            eventName.setId(current);
            eventName.setText(eName3.get(current));
            eventName.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            eventName.setTextSize(12);
            eventName.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            eventName.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 120, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()),
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tr.addView(eventName);

          //CREATE TEXT VIEW FOR EVENT TIME
            TextView eventDate = new TextView(this);
            eventDate.setId(current);
            eventDate.setText(eTime3.get(current));
            eventDate.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            eventDate.setTextSize(12);
            eventDate.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            eventDate.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 80, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()),
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tr.addView(eventDate);

            // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            final Intent i = new Intent(RsvpActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("bar_id",eId3.get(current));
            i.putExtra("fb_id", fb_id);
            i.putExtra("first_name",first_name);
            i.putExtra("last_name",last_name);
            i.putExtra("gender",gender);

            tr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     // eId3.get(current)
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });

        }


    }



    public void getRsvp(String fb_id, String url){
        String result = "";

        eId3.clear();
        eBar3.clear();
        eName3.clear();
        eTime3.clear();

        //the year data to send
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fb_id",fb_id));

           //http post
             try{
                     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                     HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                     httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                     HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                     is = entity.getContent();
             }catch(Exception e){
                 Log.e("connection","error in http client");
             }

           //convert response to string
             try{
                     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                     sb = new StringBuilder();
                     String line = "0";

                     while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                             sb.append(line + "\n");
                     }
                     is.close();
                     result=sb.toString(); 
             }catch(Exception e){
                     Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
             }


             try{
                     JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                     JSONObject json_data=null;

                     for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                             json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                             eId3.add(json_data.getString("event_id"));
                             eBar3.add(json_data.getString("bar_name"));
                             eName3.add(json_data.getString("event_name"));
                             eTime3.add(json_data.getString("date"));
                     }
                 }catch(JSONException e){
                     eId3.add("0");
                     eBar3.add("No Data");
                     eName3.add("No Data");
                     eTime3.add("No Data");
                         Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                 }


    }

}
```

Comment: Please, share DataActivity.java if possible. Probably timing issue, if You have some not clear sync between processes.

Comment: Are you using web-service and storing response in ArrayList? It may happen sometimes that your web-service call is not successful and you may be getting null for ArrayList i.e. Size is  0 and index also is 0. It would be much better if you can also show some code of your RsvpActivity.java file, where this error is appearing..

Comment: Editing my question to add the java file.

Comment: One of your list gets empty. Do you always get the exception at line 167 (maybe you could point out which one is this line) or the exception line(meaning another list gets empty) varies?

Comment: Line 167 would be i.putExtra("bar_id",eId3.get(current));

Comment: The problem could be that you start two `AsyncTask` one in the `onStart` and one in the `onResume` method. At one point you are clearing the lists so maybe at the time the first one clears the lists the other task might try to access them. Try to remove one of the tasks, for example start the task only in the `onStart` method and see if this changes things.

Comment: Yes man got it already and you're right. It's just today that I noticed that the onStart() and onResume() process runs at the same time after loading the Activity and I think it doesn't follow the flow or I just misunderstood the process. Again please put your comment on the answer so that I can choose it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem  is that you start two `AsyncTask` to do(I think) the same thing, one in the `onStart` callback and one in the `onResume` callback. Because of this you'll end up with the two tasks working with the same lists. This is most likely the reason for one of your lists to get a size of `0`, one task might just cleared the lists only to have the second task trying to access that empty list.